# Using RETURN in dynamic SQL to exit stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to use something like below in my stored procedure to exit when a certain condition is met, but the code after the return gets executed. Is there something wrong my script?

```
declare @DBName sysname
set @DBName ='Test_DB'
SET @sql='IF OBJECT_ID('''+@DBName +''',''U'') is null' + CHAR(10)+  'RETURN;' 
EXEC (@sql)
```

Comment: The problem here is that you shortened your code so much as you lost the problem you are encountering. In your example here there is nothing after the RETURN. Perhaps if you can explain what you are really trying to do we can help you.

Comment: So above code which I provided is at the very beginning of the storedproc, I trying to exit/return from the storedproc if my condition is met without proceeding to the SP code after above code.

Comment: Ahh gotcha. The dynamic sql is in fact going to return. But it will not cause the calling code to issue a RETURN also. You have a problem of scope here. What are you trying to do here? It kind of looks like you are checking for the existence of a database?

Comment: My storedproc takes dbname and other parameters, and perform few action on the database based on other if conditions which follows above code. sometimes when the database is missing, the application calling the storedproc fails. So, I was thinking of checking if the database doesnt exists, then return from the SP.

Comment: Then add your check outside of dynamic sql. And you can't check OBJECT_ID for this. You need to query sys.databases. Just put all of your dynamic sql logic inside an IF EXISTS

Comment: @Kelsey you should make your code _double-dynamic_ or split it into two separate batches. Server can not compile references to missing DB. And one more question: are you expecting that code will _return_ from inner dynamic query or will exit outer stored proc?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `INSERT/EXEC` to get the object id of the dynamic object you're checking for, then return if the table has no records not null:

```
DECLARE @DBName sysname
SET @DBName = 'Test_DB'
SET @sql='SELECT OBJECT_ID('''+@DBName +''',''U'')'
DECLARE @Results TABLE (ObjectId INT)
INSERT @Results
    EXEC (@Sql)
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @Results WHERE ObjectId IS NOT NULL)
    RETURN
```

Just a side note, `OBJECT_ID` won't match a database. You'd have to use `sys.databases` or like that.

Answer (score 0):

I tested a similar script:

```
declare @DBName sysname
set @DBName ='Test_DB'
declare @sql varchar(8000)
SET @sql='IF OBJECT_ID('''+@DBName +''',''U'') is null' +
    CHAR(10) +
    'begin select ''before return'' return end select ''after return'''
EXEC (@sql)
```

The output of this script on SQL 2014 Developer Edition was 'before return' but not 'after return'.  So the return does seem to be working as expected.